# Why does import.wig function (rtracklayer package of bioconductor) not work on R v. 2.14.2 but work in R v. 2.15.2?

Tags: r, import

When I use import.wig function on R v.2.14.2:

```
library("rtracklayer")
wig_object <- import.wig(filename, genome = "g19", asRangedData = FALSE)
```

I get an empty 'wig_object' with no error (file size of 'filename' is ~7Mb).

However, when I perform the same command on R v.2.15.2 my file gets imported and my 'wig_object' now contains all the data from my 'filename'.

Is this just a version problem or am I doing something wrong?